# snowflake identify ARRAY_CONTAINS partial match

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a partial match / using some kind of a wild card to do string matching in SNOWFLAKE arrays.

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS('HELLO'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI'))   
<TRUE>
```

Tried like this , but no luck

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS('HELL%'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI'))
<FALSE>
```

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert the array (temporarily) to string and use CONTAINS operator?

```
SELECT CONTAINS( ARRAY_TO_STRING( ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('WHY','HELLO', 'HI'),',') , 'HELL' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI') AS aa
   ,':' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(aa,';') || ':' AS bb
   ,bb like '%:HELL%'
```

so this is a dirty solution, but it would "work"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a JavaScript UDF. This example uses RegExp instead of the like function wildcards. It's overloaded so you can use standard RegExp or one with parameters (i for case insensitivity in particular). This returns a boolean to approximate the behavior of ARRAY_CONTAINS. If you want, you can do a simple modification to return the value of "i", which will be the ordinal position of the first match in the array, or -1 if it leaves the loop (not found).

```
create or replace function ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP(REGEXP_EXPRESSION string, A array)
returns boolean
language javascript
as
$$
    var rx = new RegExp(REGEXP_EXPRESSION);
    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if (A[i].search(rx) != -1) return true;
    }
    return false;
$$;

create or replace function ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP(REGEXP_EXPRESSION string, A array, REGEX_PARAMS string)
returns boolean
language javascript
as
$$
    var rx = new RegExp(REGEXP_EXPRESSION, REGEX_PARAMS);
    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if (A[i].search(rx) != -1) return true;
    }
    return false;
$$;

SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP('HELL.'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI'));  -- True. Wildcard match.
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP('HELL'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI')); -- True. Partial match.
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP('\\bHEL\\b'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI')); -- False. Full word matching.
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP('hel'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI')); -- False. Case sensitive.
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP('HeL'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI'), 'i'); -- True. Case insensitive partial match.
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS_REGEXP('\\bHeL\\b'::VARIANT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('HELLO', 'HI'), 'i'); -- False. Full word insensitive match.
```